# FUNCTION Database.GeomFromText doesnt exist in TypeORM

Tags: mysql, node.js, typescript, typeorm, geojson

I use mysql with typeorm and typescript. I have the following entity.

```
import { Entity, PrimaryGeneratedColumn, Column, OneToMany } from "typeorm";
import { Geometry } from "geojson";

@Entity({ name: 'user' })
export class User {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id!: number;

    @Column({ unique: true })
    username: string;

    @Column({ select: false })
    password: string;

    @Column({
        type: "geometry",
        nullable: true,
        srid: 4326
    })
    location: Geometry;
}
```

and a function to create user from an incoming http request

```
async createUser(req: Request, res: Response) {
    const { username, password, location } = req.body
    let validLocation: Geometry

    if (!username || !password || !location)
        return noGoodRequest(res, 'bad parameter')

    try {
        const l = JSON.parse(location)
        validLocation = {
            type: "Point",
            coordinates: [l.longitude, l.latitude]
        }
    } catch {
        return noGoodRequest(res, 'bad parameter')
    }

    const newUser = await UserRepo
        .create({ username, password, location: validLocation })

    await UserRepo.save(newUser)

    goodRequest(res)
}
```

when invoking the createUser function i get the following error and I'm stuck.

`QueryFailedError: FUNCTION mydb.GeomFromText does not exist`

I need help on this matter.

I tried changing `location: Geometry` to `location: string`
and `@Column({ type: "geometry" })` to `@Column({ type: "point" })`

Comment: GeomFromText was deprecated; your libraries should be using ST_GeomFromText instead.  are you using the latest version of them?

Comment: How do I achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set connection option with `legacySpatialSupport: false`

[image: zhe source code in typeorm]